# Remove extra zeros from value of custom attribute "ship_cost" in magento 1.9.2.3

Tags: php, magento, attributes, zero

I have a Custom Product Attribute named as 'ship_cost' with an input type 'text field'. While putting a value on back-end, it automatically adds four extra zeros after the decimal point.

I want this price in 'Rs. 45.00' format but currently it is showing as 'Rs. 45.0000'.

I have not worked with Magento for a long time, basically, I am a newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this.

A simple fix would be to just use the `number_format()` function:

```
<?php 
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $prodShipCost = $_product->getData('ship_cost'); // Or however you want to get the attribute values
    $priceFormatted = number_format($prodShipCost, 2, '.', '');
    echo $priceFormatted;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick.

```
Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->format($_product->getData('ship_cost'), array('display'=>Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL), false);
```

Comment: This is a core magento method whereas David Wilkinson's answer is straight php.